# How do I access the friend function objects with my derived classes in seperate files?

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, header-files, virtual-functions

I have 3 separate header files. Class A, Class B is derived A and Class.

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void foo(C ...object...);
};

class B : public A {
public:
    void foo(C ...object...);
};

class C {
public:
    friend class A;
    friend class B;
private:
    A *arr[num][num];
};
```

Arr is pointer of 2D array.The inside of the 2D array is filled with B objects.How can I access the C class object from the header file of class B? Is it possible?If possible, how should the "include .h" seperates header files and foo function prototype be?

Comment: What include patterns have you tried?  Did they fail?

Comment: not nested class.

Comment: have a look at [forward declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/what-are-forward-declarations-in-c)

Comment: @StephenNewell I have tried many combinations but it did not work. I cannot introduce the Class C object in the header file with Class B. There is include A.h and B.h in Class C for friend definition. And I get a lot of errors when I try to include C.h in the Class B or Class A header files.

Comment: Use forward declarations in `class C`. You can even use them in all 3 header files. Include the headers just in the source files.

Comment: `class B : public A{} {` --- does `A{}` a typo?

Comment: So post those exact errors.  And start smaller, adding dependencies as you need them.  Until A.h can be #included without error, don't even touch the other files.

Comment: @KorelK Sorry I edited.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A common way to split your code into separate files is following:

- A.h

  ```
  #pragma once
  class C;

  class A {
  public:
      virtual void foo(C c);
  };
  ```

  Class `A` doesn't need any type information of `C`. The declaration of member function `foo` doesn't need complete type information but a declaration because the function expects a parameter of type `C`.
- A.cpp

  ```
  #include "A.h"
  #include "C.h"

  void A::foo(C c) {}
  ```

  The definition of function `A::foo(C c)` needs complete type information of `C`. Therefore the class definition of `C` is included.
- B.h

  ```
  #pragma once
  #include "A.h"

  class C;

  class B : public A {
  public:
       void foo(C c) override;
  };
  ```

  Class `B` needs complete type information of `A` for inheritance. Therefore the class definition of `A` is included. Complete type information of class `C` is not necessary (see A.h).
- B.cpp

  ```
  #include "B.h"
  #include "C.h"

  void B::foo(C c) {}
  ```

  Same as in A.cpp
- C.h

  ```
  #pragma once
  class A;

  class C {
  public:
       friend class A;
       friend class B;
  private:
       A *arr[5][5];
  };
  ```

  Class `C` just contains friend declarations of `A` and `B` and a pointer to type `A`. A friend declaration don't need a declaration or full type information. Since all pointers to objects have same size complete type information for class `A` is not necessary. It will become necessary when the pointer is dereferenced.

All source files also contain an include of the corresponding header file.